# Run SP 2010 VS workflow under workflow manager

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager

I have very complex SP 2010 Visual studio workflow & after migration to SharePoint 2013, its not working properly. Microsoft support team asked us to install Workflow Manager and run the workflow under it.

Now the problem is how to do that? OR what changes do I need to make in old 2010 visual studio workflow so that it will run under 2013 workflow manager?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 new approach for the workflow as they are hosted and process in Worfklow manager 1.0. Code based Workflows not supported for 2013 platform but still can be run but in 2010 compatibility mode.

I think you have to re-write the your workflow in SharePoint 2013 platform as these will be declarative workflows.

Workflows are now fully declarative, meaning that their definition and execution paths are actually described in a series of XAML files.

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/workflows-sharepoint-2013-isn-t-your-dad-s-workflow

Comment: Thanks Waqas.... I was thinking the same but looking for any way if exist to do this because re-writing this workflow will take few months time.